# searching a .txt. file from another .txt file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, linear-search

I will probably get some scrutiny about my question but at this point I will take whatever I can get. I will try and make what I'm having trouble with as simple as possible in a step by step objective.

I'm trying to:

```
Read in a .txt file of keywords
print them
read in .txt resume(the program is a resume scanner)
search the resume for the keywords
output the keyword with the count of ho many times they were used.
```

I can output both the resume array and keyword array but when I get to the search and output part it breaks. I'm trying to see if I'm even close with my search code.

My professor gave us this assignment a while back and I couldn't figure out the search and output part of it. Now I have some free time I wanted to go back and try and figure it out with no luck. Below is the code I have. I want to apologize for the length, I'm not trying to blast this post with a bunch of code but feel like its all relevant. I will take the bad rep on here if I can at least learn this. I feel like this is really important. Thank you all in advance!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#include <string.h>


main(){
FILE* pFile;
FILE* resume;
char f[50] = { "" };
char r[50] = { "" };
char search = "";
int i = 0, j = 0;
int count = 0, c = 0;

printf("Read in the keywords\n\n");//read in keywords
pFile = fopen("a:\\newA.txt", "r");
if (!pFile) {
    perror("Error");
}
fread(f, sizeof(char), 50, pFile);//read in keywords into char array
for (i = 0; i<50; i++) {
    if (f[i] == ',') {
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", f[i]);
    }
}//end for loop
printf("\n\n");
pause;//end reading in keywords

//read in resume
cls;
resume = fopen("a:\\resume.txt", "r");
if (!resume) {
    perror("Error");
}
    fread(r, sizeof(char), 50, resume);//read in resume into char array
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        if (r[j] == ',') {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("%c", r[j]);
        }
}//end for loop
    printf("\n\n");
    pause;
// end reading in resume
```

Below is where I'm having the break happen

```
//beginning search
for (c = 0; c < i; c++)
{
    if (f[i] == r[c])//if keyword match resume add counter
    {
        count++;//counter
    }
}//end for loop
if (count == 0)
    printf("\n%s is not present in array.\n", search);//no matches
else
    printf("\n%s is present %d times in array.\n\n", search, count);//keyword match and how many times found

pause;//end search and output

}
```

Comment: You've not explained the problem you're having with the code you posted, and you've not asked a question that can be answered."I can't figure it out" is not a useful problem description. If you want help here, you need to be specific - we're not a site for "Here's a bunch of code. Fix it for me. Be back later to pick it up." type questions, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I edited the question and I will respond here as well. The search portion is what breaks. I'm able to print both the arrays fine but when I get to searching the resume with pFile it breaks. Again thanks!

Comment: Your edit doesn't help much. "it breaks" isn't any more specific than "I can't figure it out". What does **breaks** mean specifically? In what way does it "break"? You also still have not asked a **specific question** that can be answered. I'll repeat: If you want help here, **you need to be specific**.

Comment: Again I apologize for not being clear. My code for my search portion errors with the following:

Comment: errors with the following:

'Unhandled exception 0x0F22FB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in resume.exe: Access violation reading location 0x00000058'

Then it stops the program without output. I'm trying to see if the second set of code will work in order to search the resume file with  pFile then output the counted results of each of the found keywords. I hope I'm making sense I apologize if I'm not.

Comment: That sort of access violation error - with a low-values address - is symtomatic of abusing a null pointer. Have a look to see if you are passing a pointer invalidly.

Comment: First, it does not have a cut-out of the word. Your code I just only display. You can Count & Find the word that is specified in the bsearch   if the keyword arranged in the order already after you have to register the keyword.